# How can I insert key as a class in map STL in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

What is the problem in below program, why i am not able to initialize map with class as a Key

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class User
{
    int value_1;
    int value_2;
public:
    User( int num_1, int num_2)
    {
        value_1 = num_1;
        value_2 = num_2;
    }
    int getId(){
        return value_1;
    }
    int getUid(){
        return value_2;
    }
    bool operator< (const User& userObj) const
    {
        if(userObj.value_1 < this->value_1)
            return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<User, int> m_UserInfoMap;

    m_UserInfoMap.insert(std::make_pair<User, int>(User(1,2), 100) );
    m_UserInfoMap.insert(std::make_pair<User, int>(User(3,4), 120) );
    m_UserInfoMap.insert(std::make_pair<User, int>(User(5,6), 300) );
    std::map<User, int>::iterator it = m_UserInfoMap.begin();
    for(; it != m_UserInfoMap.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout<<it->first.getId()<<" :: "<<it->second<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In above program if I try to add key as a class it is giving error.
And please tell different ways to initialize map.

Comment: if I try to initialize map Like : 
m_UserInfoMap[a] = 1; it is working properly"
but if 
std::map<User, int> m_UserInfoMap = (a,1); or 
std::map<User, int> m_UserInfoMap (a,1);
it is not working, so whats worng with above statements?

Comment: We are not going to do your compiler's work *again*. Post the error.

Comment: Crank up your warning levels. You have a trivial mistake: a non-void function *always* has to return something.

Comment: which non void function r u talking about?
I am asking about make_pair function inside insert part of map.

Comment: You only defined three functions. Read them and find the one with the problem.

Comment: The only errors in the code you posted are the lack of a `return` in your `operator<` and the lack of `const`-qualification of `getId`, neither of which seem to be what you're actually asking about.  Can you clarify what your actual question is?

Comment: If there is a reason your `operator <` isn't simply `return userObj.value_1 < value_1;` I can't think of it. (btw you've effectively implemented that to mean `this->value_1` must be strictly *greater* than `userObj->value_1` for `*this` to be considered strictly *less* than `userObj`; hope that was the intent).

Answer (score 5):

[`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)'s `value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`, means keys are saved as `const`. So you can't call non-const member functions on them like `std::cout<<it->first.getId()`.

You should change `User::getId()` (and `User::getUid()`) to const member functions. Such as:

```
int getId() const {
//          ~~~~~
    return value_1;
}
int getUid() const {
//           ~~~~~
    return value_2;
}
```

BTW: You didn't return anything when `if` condition fails in `operator<`.

```
bool operator< (const User& userObj) const
{
    if(userObj.value_1 < this->value_1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;  // return for else case
}
```

or just

```
bool operator< (const User& userObj) const
{
    return userObj.value_1 < this->value_1;
}
```

Comment: `if(condition) return true; else return false;` is bad style, better not to show such stuff at all...

Comment: @Aconcagua I agree that. I want to emhpasize that OP should also return sth for the implicit else case too. Anyway, I wrote the simplest one at last. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should make your operator always return a value:

```cpp
bool operator< (const User& userObj) const
{
    return userObj.value_1 < this->value_1;
}
```

Are you sure you really want to compare `x < y` as `y.value < x.value`? Otherwise, you need to change the comparison inside:

```cpp
bool operator< (const User& userObj) const
{
    return this->value_1 < userObj.value_1;
}
```

And while writing this answer, songyuanyao has been faster than me for the second part, so have a look at his answer...